Android auto text size results in different sizes
I have an application containing a screen displaying god names in Islam.
it displays them in a grid view. I use autoSizeTextType attribute to adapt to different screen sizes. However, it shows undesired behavior as each name is displayed in a different size from the others which results in what is shown here: Here is the screenshot
And here's my code:
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGodName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:minHeight="46dp"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans_arabic_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:scaleX="-1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_22ssp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="الله"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

So, could you tell me the best practice for achieving the best adaptation for different screen sizes for text without facing this problem?

Using textAppearance with Typography attributes from the Material Design guidelines is the best practice. Please note that you should avoid using textSize or similar attributes that alter the size of TextView if you use it.
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBodyLarge"
    ... />

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceTitleLarge"
    ... />

If it still does not fit your need, you can set different text sizes for different screen sizes by providing alternative resources.

Create /res/values/dimens.xml file for the default text size.
<resources>
<dimen name="my_text">22sp</dimen>
</resources>


For screen sizes that have smallest width 600dp, create values-sw600dp folder under res folder. Then create dimens.xml in it.
<resources>
<dimen name="my_text">24sp</dimen>
</resources>


Then we can set text size like this.
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
     android:textSize="@dimen/my_text"
     ... />




I've tried your first solution by adding MaterialTextView and it really helped me achieving what I need. Thank you very much.

@YasmineRaafat If this answer works well, please mark it as accepted answer. For more information, please follow this link.
